# Excel Sumproduct

Tags: worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2013

I have an excel sheet with multiple days on it lets say in a random order. I want to sum product by supervisor and day. How can I make the equation so it only sums the "product" of the supervisor but only on a certain day?

Comment: Can you please clarify your question (maybe even add some sample data)? Because the better your question is asked, the better we can answer it.

Answer (score 2):

You aren't able to sum text, only number values. However, you could try sorting the data.

On a Mac, select the data you want to sort, go to 'Data' on the task bar, then 'Sort...'. Sort by date column first, then repeat the process to sort by supervisor.

If you're trying to get excel to only show rows of a certain date, then (as explained above) sort the data by date, then optionally hide/delete the unwanted rows to work with only the desired date. If you're summing hours worked on a certain date, then select a nearby empty cell and type " =sum(C1:C45) " (replacing C1 through C45 with the appropriate cells.) This will produce a sum of the hours worked.

Does this answer your question?